# Inserting values into a table if the condition in a select query isnt met

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table t1 in my oracle database

```
id        name
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
5           E
```

I have used a sequence to add the ids to the table

```
INSERT INTO t1 (t1seq.nextval, 'A')
```

I want to now select the id associated with a specific name from the table and if it doesn't exist, insert the name into t1.

```
SELECT FROM t1 WHERE name = 'F'
```

should insert a row to t1 if it doesn't exist, I'm trying to use IF EXISTS in oracle but receiving errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this trick

SQL :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = 'F')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'DATA EXIST'); 
    RETURN
END

INSERT INTO t1(id,name) values (t1seq.nextval, 'F')
```

thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function something like this

```
...
BEGIN
  SELECT ID INTO LV_ID FROM T1 WHERE NAME = P_IN_NAME;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  LV_ID := NULL;
END;

IF LV_ID IS NULL THEN 
  LV_ID := T1SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  INSERT INTO T1(ID, NAME) VALUES (LV_ID, P_IN_NAME);
END IF;
...
```

RETURN LV_ID;